# Magento Install issues

Tags: magento2, .htaccess

Hi I've installed Magento 2 in a directory  : var/www/html/magento2

There seems to be two problems I'm experiencing:

When I browse to http://....aws.com/ I can see contents of html folder and lists the Magento2 folder. Then clicking on this folder opens up the home page of magento.

Then when I try to access admin page (http://....aws.com/magento2/admin) I'm not seeing the admin page.

Where should the .htaccess be located and what should the RewriteBase be set to pls?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**For http://....aws.com/magento2/admin:**

Please check **`app/etc/env.php`** file that what admin path has been set in this file.

It may be possible that while installing magento you may not have noticed but admin path was set something else.

**For http://....aws.com/:**

If you want your base URL to be http://....aws.com/, then it would be great if you move your content out of magento2 folder and then set base url in core_config_data table.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Checked env.php and admin is correct. I had same problem when installing another instance using Bitnami, I could not access the admin areas either. This time I've installed manually. Maybe linked to aws somehow ?

Comment: Please check whether mod_rewrite is active or not.

Answer (score 0):

I've re-installed and seems to work now. I think it was a permissions problem. Thanks